# Salesforce: Getting "PORTAL_NO_ACCESS" error message while creating user in Salesforce for some profiles

Tags: java, soap, salesforce

Currently am facing an issue while creating an user in salesforce via API. Getting "PORTAL_NO_ACCESS" error message. This happens only when i add particular profile to the user. It works fine with some profiles. Please suggest why is it so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means access to the specified portal is not available for the profile you assigned. You have to enable this profile for that specified portal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply much appreciated. Couple of questions: 1>How can we find all available portals for my SF instance?  2>How can we enable particular profile for the specified portal?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/02/customer-portal-implementation-in.html